# Formula of TEXT in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to create a calculeted field on sharepoint 2010 I have a list with a field named start date of date time type, I need to calculate Year and month from this field, I'm using this formula `=TEXT(YEAR([Start Date]),"0000")&"-"&TEXT(MONTH(start Date]),"00")` but I get this error:

> The formula contains a syntax error or unsupported.

What can I do? What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you can get calculate field month and year from date field using below formula

for year

```
 =TEXT([DateFieldName],"yy")
```

for month

```
 =TEXT([DateFieldName],"mm")
```

Comment: you can check all other format on msdn
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx

Comment: And this one all possible values for the Text function: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-29cea14b-bd86-426c-9985-cb2f0b19df58?CorrelationId=d25b1b5c-d056-41e9-88b7-edc4b2906b8d&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solution was `;` instead `,`

```
=[IMIE]&"-"&TEXT([Data];"dd-mm-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same problem.
It seems, that there are regional settings that cause a problem together with mostly english based references and automatic translations.

If regional settings have a comma as decimal separator, then the separator in the function is no longer a comma but a semicolon.